# nginx rewrite url to lowercase url

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, rewrite, mono

I have nginx setup, however I'm needing to fix an issue where someone types "/Home" to:

- rewrite it to the lowercase "/home" (do this to all files and directories, not just home) but locate the Uppercase (if there is one) file.
- Or do I need to add another location that uses the case-insensitive characters "~*" ?

The actual directory and file layout does contain mixed Upper and lower case characters. I would like to preserve this for simplicity sake, i.e. /Home and /About are the actual directories, but for SEO I want to permanent redirect to the lowercase /home but find the actual /Home directory.

I'm not sure if this can be accomplished by a rewrite rule or if there is a case insensitivity on the "location / { }" or some combination.

```
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /Home;
        }
```

***Note:*** I'm not looking for answers that fall into [Nginx Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/), [including the evil Ifs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: One option is to use an additional location block that matches any upper case characters, and contains a rewrite to the lowercase uri. You can perform the string manipulation needed using the embedded perl module (e.g. [like this](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,48527,55242#msg-55242))

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments to your question, this is possible by use of perl module. Assuming you'll use that `$uri_lowercase` you may write something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri_lowercase $uri_lowercase/ =404;
}
```

Note however that $uri_lowercase may not fit your needs if you have mixed case URLs like `/Home/UseR/teSt.html` and you need to try all bunch of *partially* lowercased uri. If this is your case i strongly advice to get some policy on your directories and require them to be lowercase.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make it easier for dev's in how they currently work and having to not rename a bunch of files and directories. Basically a uri of /Home to do a permanent redirect to /home, but have the /home match the physical /Home directory? Make sense? Kind of stupid, but going for SEO and moving from MSFT website to Linux. From what you've provided (I'll double check) it looks like uri of /home will *not* match the physical dir /Home